# Incompatible parameter list when converting from Delphi 7 to Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, udp, delphi-7, delphi-10.3-rio

I have this app that I'm trying to convert, but I have some issues with server communication. This line:

`procedure UDPServerUDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);`

that gives me this error:

*The UDPServerUDPRead method referenced by UDPServer.OnUDPRead has an incompatible parameter list. Remove the reference?*

That procedure is used like this:

```
procedure TFrmMain.UDPServerUDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  Buffer: Tarray1024ofChar ;
  count: Integer;
begin
  count := AData.Size;
  if count > Length(Buffer) then exit;
  AData.Read(Buffer, count);
  if UDPServerActive then DataReceived(count,ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,Buffer);
end;
```

What is wrong with it? What should I change?

Comment: By upgrading your Delphi version you have also upgraded the Indy version that you are using, presuming that you are using the Indy supplied with Delphi. So look at the source code for Indy, find the event in question, and look at what has changed. As the error message explains, the parameter list for the event has changed.

Comment: In Indy included with Delphi 10.3, the event handler has this profile: procedure TFrmMain.UDPServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);

Comment: Ok, I updated the procedure and i changed `count := AData.Size;` to `count := Length(AData);`

How should I change `AData.Read(Buffer, count);`?

Comment: That code reads from a stream into an array. But you don't need to do that because you are now provided an array. You will need to spend a little time understanding what your code does. Moving from pre-Unicode Delphi to Unicode Delphi is a very significant task. Understanding your code is critical. No shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the `TIdUDPServer.OnUDPRead` event changed from Indy 9 to Indy 10.

In Indy 9, when a data packet arrives, you are given a `TStream` object wrapping the raw data.

In Indy 10, when a data packet arrives, you are given a `TIdBytes` byte array of the raw data.

So you need to update your code accordingly, eg:

```pascal
type
  // Char is a 1-byte AnsiChar in D7, but is a 2-byte WideChar in D2009+!
  Tarray1024ofChar = array[0..1023] of AnsiChar{Char} // or, use Byte instead...

...

procedure TFrmMain.UDPServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  Buffer: Tarray1024ofChar;
  count: Integer;
begin
  count := Length(AData);
  if count > Length(Buffer) then exit;
  BytesToRaw(AData, Buffer, count);
  if UDPServerActive then
    DataReceived(count, ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, Buffer);
end;
```

If you can change `DataReceived()` to accept a `PAnsiChar` (or `PByte`) instead of a `Tarray1024ofChar`, you can simplify the code further by getting rid of the local `Buffer` variable altogether:

```pascal
procedure TFrmMain.UDPServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  if UDPServerActive then
    DataReceived(Length(AData), ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, PAnsiChar{PByte}(AData));
end;
```